# Xero Payslip List

Tags: javascript, xero-api

I can get a payslip's information by this api

```
GET https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Payslip/5037f8ef-e9b5-40a6-9ec1-0f6f7ebb4787.
```

But I need all the payslip list's api. Beacuse I want to integrate this api in my system and get all the payslip for my xero organaigation aslo in employee wise.

Is it possible? If Possible then how? Please assist me.

Thanks.

I can get a payslip's information by this api

```
GET https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Payslip/5037f8ef-e9b5-40a6-9ec1-0f6f7ebb4787.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to get a list of all payslips as a single call.

You need to first make a call to the payruns endpoint to get a payrun id, make a call to each pay run id for the period you are interested in to get a list of payslip ids and then query each of these separately.